# django model's methods

Tags: python, django, methods, model, field

is there a better way to handle those functions inside the model?

```
class MyModel ( models.Model ):
    name = models.CharField( max_length=50 )
    foo = models.CharField( max_length=50 )

    def style_foo():
        return '<a href="/contract/print/sample/%s/">%s</a>' % ( self.pk, _( 'View sample' ) )

    style_foo.allow_tags = True
    style_foo.short_description = _('Style sample')
```

I have pretty much overloaded model itself. Those functions makes my model file barely unreadable. I have tens of them. I need those.

I am doing an CRM system with heavy contrib.admin templates overloading, therefore sometimes it easier to write a one or a two line method, and use it on Admin model's list_display = () and not rewrite template admin/change_list_result.html only in order to change one line.

I tried to define model fields in one class and inherit in class with those methods, but this is quite odd.

Do you have any suggestions?

[This is a sample model for this usecase](http://code.google.com/p/django-pool-crm/source/browse/trunk/crm/contract/models/contract.py)

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'those'?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but this might be helpful. First, as a general rule, you shouldn't put formatting/display type of information (such as HTML) into the Model level. You should format the HTML elsewhere, and design the Model so as to return a URL for any given object. For instance:

```
# views.py
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('view-sample', [self.pk])

# urls.py
from myapps.models import view_sample
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^contract/print/sample/(?P<sample>.*)/$', view_sample, name='view-sample'),

# view_template.html
<p><a href="{{ anySample.get_absolute_url }}">Click to view sample</a></p>
```

Comment: @Alex, yes, but it wasn't based on what you said. :) I suspect we started answering at the same time, it just took me longer to type in formatted code. :)

Comment: @ John C, Yup, thats why I upped your answer. You had code, I did not :)

Comment: Look at my code example (link in the question) and check this usecase: `list_display = ( 'season', 'uid_decorator', 'customer_decorator', 'comment2_decorator', 'group_decorator', 'day_decorator', 'type_decorator', 'comment_decorator', 'signup_date', 'resignation_date' )`

Answer (score 1):

Would [get_absolute_url](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#get-absolute-url) work for what you're trying to do? You just offload the anchor tag into your template and use the get_absolute_url() method to get the url. If you then use the [permalink decorator](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#django.db.models.permalink) you can tie it right into your url routing. Any change to your urls for the contract/print/sample view will be automatically reflected throughout your site without having to update your models.py file to match the new url structure.